# Wcf Domain Service vs Silverlight Enabled Wcf services

Tags: wcf, silverlight-5.0

I am working with silverlight project that is consuming domain services. Actually i find that quite messy as one domain service class and metadata. I have already worked with Wcf services and found them very easy to update and handle. But domain service's modification (as new field or tables are added) is really a pain.

I want to know why people prefer domain services over silverlight enabled Wcf services? I mean advantages or disadvantages of both and performance implication

Answer (score 1):

**After goggling i found this are things you should see :**

- To authenticate users faster in the domain
- To authenticate resources(gps etc) faster for the users
- Utilization of resources
- Utilization of network and descreasing the overall traffic in the
  network.
- The main benefit is that of the users and passwords management, which
  could grow to be massive amount of work having to manage them
  individually on each independent servers. The proposed changes of
  migrating the whole platform to Active Directory environment will
  assist in propagating the changes (such as new users, password
  changes, new security requirements via GPO, etc) on to the servers
  (which will run as domain clients, only 1 or 2 will run Primary and
  Secondary ADC. Not all these servers are going to run host AD or be
  an ADC, server OS is used due to it's robustness and reliability).

**disadvantage**

- cost of infrastructure
- good planning is must
- Complex structure for user